# Dijkstra's algorithm with secondary cost limitation

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path, dijkstra, multiple-conditions

As part of a school assignment, I am required to implement Dijkstra's algorithm on a weighted, cyclic graph with a caveat - there exist a secondary weight/cost (henceforth referred to as **B**) on each edge, and the algorithm is to find the shortest path from a source node to a target node while keeping total **B** to be under a certain constant value.

On top of basic Dijkstra's, I have added an additional condition to the relaxation/update condition, which is that the current shortest path must be under the constant **B** value given.

```
if (no shortest path yet exists to neighbour node X or the current shortest path to the neighbour node is longer than the current shortest path to current node + current edge to neighbour node) and total **B** of current shortest path to current node + current edge to neighbour node is less than input **B** value:

   update current shortest path to neighbour node
```

However, the result returned, is neither the shortest path or has the lowest **B**. In other words, there exists other paths with lower distance as well as cost **B**. May I ask what is the problem with my understanding?

Edit: Current Code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, node, p): 
        self.node = node
        self.p = p

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.p < other.p
    

def b_dijkstra(G, S, T, constraint):
    start = [Node(S, 0.0)]                       # Creating initial start node using HeapQ and setting its value to 0.0
    goal = set()
    pred = dict()                                                         # Dictionary to store visited nodes in a graph
    dist = dict()                                                     # Dictionary to store distance from point to point
    b = dict()
    pred[S] = None
    dist[S] = 0.0
    b[S] = 0.0
    count = 0
    while start:
        count += 1
        C = hq.heappop(start).node                   # Pop the smallest item off the heap, maintaining the heap invariant.
        if C == T:
            print('Nodes searched:',count)
            print(' b:', b[C])
            return traversal(T, pred)
        goal.add(C)
        #for each neighbour
        for pointer in G[C]:
            if pointer in goal:
                continue
            dist_temp = dist[C] + G[C][pointer]['weight']
            b_temp =  b[C] + G[C][pointer]['b']
            if (pointer not in dist or dist[pointer] > dist_temp) and constraint >= b_temp: #if stored distance is greater than the calculated distance
                dist[pointer] = dist_temp
                pred[pointer] = C
                b[pointer] =  b_temp
                hq.heappush(start, Node(pointer, dist[C] + G[C][pointer]['weight']))          # Adding vertex to queue
    return []
```

Comment: Please post your current code

Comment: Usually, when an assignment like this is given, there are constraints that limit B to a few different values, which makes the problem tractable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have this graph (weights given as weight/B) with a limit on B of 15. What will your algorithm do? If I understand you correctly, it will first find the shortest path to A costing 1/10 and then fail to find any path to End satisfying the condition on B. Is my understanding correct? If yes, it should be clear what is wrong with your algorithm.

[image: Sample graph]

Comment: Hmm, if that is the case, wouldn't Dijkstra simply continue expanding node B in your graph, leading to a final solution of distance 13, and B 10? As the termination condition is not met.

Comment: @asdj1234 Why don't you try it yourself? The thing is, once Dijkstra marks a node as "visited" (meaning you are sure you already found the shortest path), it is never checked again.

Comment: you are right, just tested it with your graph structure and it indeed does not work. Does this mean I should modify Dijkstra such that I can backtrack again later on?

Comment: Or perhaps a way to generate a single weight from the 2 costs?

Comment: @asdj1234 I don't think any single weight could possibly work, since you never know whether some value of B is good enough, until you find it isn't. I'd try keeping a list of all "reasonable" distances to every node ("reasonable" meaning it's better then all other distances in at least one criterion).